# Forms auth redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

while Forms auth redirecting page not loading CSS an js file in MVC. default it's redirect to `login.aspx` page so  I gave  code in web config like this:

```
<system.web> 
<authentication mode="None" >
    <forms loginUrl="Home/Index" >  </forms>
</authentication>
 <system.web> 

<location path="Content">             
   <system.web>             
     <authorization>             
       <allow users="*" />             
     </authorization>             
   </system.web>             
 </location>
```

it's redirection correct but `css` and `js` files not loaded.

i seen request using firebug like this

```
**url/Home/Index?ReturnUrl=%2FScripts%2Fjquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js**
```

What's wrong in this code please help me.

Thanks,

S.Somu

Answer (score 0):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="login" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="6000" protection="All" path="/"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
```

And after /system.web tag give following code. You can mention your resource names  wherever applicable

```
<location path="images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="js">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```